# Convergence of this sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the sequence
$$
y_n= \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+  \frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\ldots+ \frac{1}{(n+n)^2}
$$
converges to zero.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, could you include some of your own attempt on this question in your post?

Answer (score 5):

We have 
$$
\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n+n)^{2}} < \frac{n}{n^{2}} = \frac{1}{n} \to 0
$$
as $n$ grows.

Answer (score 1):

Because
$$0 < y_n < \frac{n}{(n+1)^2}$$
and $\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}$ converges to zero.

**OBS**
$$
\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} > \frac{1}{(n+2)^2} > ... > \frac{1}{(n+n)^2}
$$